# Is there something like ClientConfig.setConnectionAttemptLimit() in Hazelcast 4.2?

Tags: java, connection, client, hazelcast

I have a scenario in which I want to instantiate a Hazelcast client in Java and if the Hazelcast client cannot connect to it's cluster, it should be shutdown and a fall-back code should be in place. So let's say the Hazelcast client is kind of a should-have, but not a must-have.

In version 3.x of Hazelcast, I had the opportunity to call `HazelcastClientConfig.setConnectionAttemptLimit(1);` In Hazelcast 4.2, I cannot figure out how to establish the same scenario. There is no method `ClientConfig.setConnectionAttemptLimit(...);` or something similar.

Has anyone an idea of how to set the initial connect attempts to 1?

I could probably implement a code like this:

```
// ...

    ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
    
    clientConfig.getNetworkConfig().addAddress(String.format("%s:%s", hazelcastServerHost, hazelcastServerPort));
    
    clientConfig.getConnectionStrategyConfig().setAsyncStart(true);
    
        // The following code  is a really dirty solution in case that HC client cannot connect to it's cluster.
        // Only works with clientConfig.getConnectionStrategyConfig().setAsyncStart(true);
        
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000); // Let's assume that a HC instance should probably be connected in 5 seconds.
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        try {
            hcClient.getMap("DUMMY"); // perform a dummy access in order to receive a HazelcastClientOfflineException if the client is not connected.
        } catch (HazelcastClientOfflineException e){
            hcClient.shutdown();
        }
        
        return hcClient;
```

But I think this is more then dirty...

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.2/migration-guides#changes-in-client-connection-retry-mechanism

The connection-attempt-period and connection-attempt-limit configuration have been removed. Instead, the elements of connection-retry.

To achieve the same thing that you were doing, you can do the following:

```
ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
ClientConnectionStrategyConfig connectionStrategyConfig = 
config.getConnectionStrategyConfig()
      .getConnectionRetryConfig()
      .setClusterConnectTimeoutMillis(5000);
```

With this setting, if a client can not connect to cluster in 5 seconds, it will shutdown similar to old setting with `connection-attempt-limit` and `connection-attempt-period`. See the following link for details
https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.2/clients/java#configuring-client-connection-retry